# UISearchBar in UINavigationBar can not change height?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I create a `UISearchBar` and set it frame size to `CGSize(260, 30)`; and I add this `UISearchBar` to `UINavigationBar` using:

```
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

But when this app run, this search bar's height is changed to **44**?
How this happened, and how to fix this problem?

[**Screenshot** when this situation happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEAvs.png)

Answer (score 1):

The height of navigation bar is 44 and you are adding search bar to navigation bar's view as subview.That is why height changes to 44.You need to hide navigation bar and use custom view which contains UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this bug myself.
I created a container view to container searchBar, and add this container view to navigation bar, and it shows successfully.